# Get stdout from curl using Popen

Tags: python, curl, stdout

This code is not working as expected:

```
cmd = subprocess.Popen(["curl"], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
(out,err) = cmd.communicate()
print(out)
print(err)
```

`out` is an empty line and `err` is `None`, instead the output is printed into the console.

I was expecting the output to be stored into a out variable, I'm using Windows 7 and Python 2.7.

How to read the output into a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `curl` on the command line and you'll get an error message because you didn't supply required parameters. You didn't get anything in `out` because `curl` wrote the error message to `stderr`. And you didn't get `err` because you didn't redirect that pipe in `Popen`. Try this instead:

```
cmd = subprocess.Popen(["curl"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out,err = cmd.communicate()
print('out:', out)
print('err:', err)
print('returncode:', cmd.returncode)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Works fine